# Determine the number of distinct characteristic polynomial in $M_{2 \times 2} ( Z_{2})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine the number of distinct characteristic polynomial in $M_{2 \times 2} ( Z_{2})$ $?$

The question has already been asked here before. But that didn't clear my doubt.

The answer is $4$.

$t^{2}, t(t+1), t^{2} +1, t^{2} + t +1$

Can't we find more polynomials.
For example the matrix with all four entries $1$ is in  $M_{2 \times 2} ( Z_{2})$ $?$ and its characteristic polynomial is $t^{2} -2t$.

Comment: But $t^2 - 2t = t^2$ in $\Bbb Z_2$!

Comment: This is over ${\mathbb Z}_2$, i.e. the integers mod $2$, so $t^2 - 2 t = t^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I answer the more general question of the number of characteristic polynomials of matrices in $M_{n \times n}(\Bbb Z_2)$, which was originally posed by our OP Mathsaddict before editing.  Obviously, $n = 2$ is a special case of this general result.

First, an example: let

$A \in M_{3 \times 3}(\Bbb Z_2), \; A = I; \tag 1$

that is,

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 2$

then

$A - tI = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - t & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1- t & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 - t \end{bmatrix}, \tag 3$

whence

$\det (A - tI) = (1 - t)^3 = 1 - 3t + 3t^2 - t^3 \equiv t^3 + t^2 + t + 1 \mod 2. \tag 4$

The above example was constructed in light of the original (unedited) version of the question in which the class of matrices under consideration was stated to be $M_{n \times n}(\Bbb Z_2)$; it is meant to show the existence of characteristic polynomials of degree other than $2$ for matrices in this class.

These things being said, we proceed with the general case of $M_{n \times n}(\Bbb Z_2)$:

Now let

$p(t) \in \Bbb Z_2[t], \; \deg p(t) = n, \tag 5$

***viz.***

$p(t) = \displaystyle \sum_0^n p_i t^i, \; p_i \in \Bbb Z_2, \; 0 \le i \le n; \tag 6$

we observe that $p(t)$ is *monic*, that is,

$p_n = 1 \in \Bbb Z_2; \tag 7$

consider the matrix

$C \in M_{n \times n}(\Bbb Z_2),  \tag 8$

$C = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & p_0 \\ 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & p_1 \\ 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & p_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & p_{n - 1} \end{bmatrix}; \tag 9$

we have

$\det(C - tI) = \det \left (  \begin{bmatrix} -t & 0 & \ldots & 0 & p_0 \\ 1 & -t & \ldots & 0 & p_1 \\ 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & p_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & p_{n - 1} - t \end{bmatrix} \right ); \tag{10}$

when this determinant is expanded in minors along the last ($n$-th) column we obtain

$\det(C - tI) = \displaystyle \sum_0^n p_i t^i = p(t) \in \Bbb Z_2[t], \tag{11}$

where we have used the fact that

$-p_i = p_i, \; p_i \in \Bbb Z_2. \tag{12}$

The preceding discussion reveals that every polynomial as in (5)-(7) is in fact the characteristic polynomial of some $n \times n$ matrix over $\Bbb Z_2$.  How many such polynomials are there?  Since each such polynomial is monic, there are $n$ free coefficients $p_0$, $p_1$, . . ., $p_{n - 1}$, each of which may arbitrarily take on the values $0, 1 \in \Bbb Z_2$; thus their number *in toto* is $2^n$; this is the number of characteristic polynomials of matrices $C \in M_{n \times n}(\Bbb Z_2)$; the case $n = 2$ thus yields $2^2 = 4$ possible polynomials over $\Bbb Z_2$, corroborating the work of our OP.